# Custom ContentProvider for complex sql database with multiple tables

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to create a library that includes functionality in an already written app.  The old app uses a complex sqlite database.  I am trying to reuse the old database as the backend for a content provider and can't figure out what would be "best practice" for what I am trying to do and how to adapt the various examples ([this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/), [this](https://github.com/vladimirvivien/workbench/tree/master/android-tutorials/ContentProviderSample/src/demo/contentprovider), and others) I have found to my situation.

Supoose you have this database structure

```
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Root |   Folder    |    Item     |  Subitem   |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| _id  | _id         | _id         | _id         |
| uuid | parent_uuid | parent_uuid | parent_uuid |
|      | uuid        | uuid        | uuid        |
|      | name        | name        | name        |
|      | data        | data        | data        |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
Root->Folder->Item->Subitem
```

Before, I used a DbAdapter class where I provided function calls that took parameters such as parent_uuid, handled all the sql query stuff inside the function, then returned a cursor with the results

example function stubs:

- get_items_by_parent_uuid(folder_uuid)
- get_item_by_uuid(uuid)
- same for Subitem also

Complex queries

- get_items_for_root(root_uuid)

  - returns cursor with item uuid, item name, item data, folder name
- get_items_with_subitem_count(folder_uuid)

  - returns cursor with item uuid, item name, item data, count of subitems where subitem.parent_uuid == item.uuid

I can't figure out the best way to provide the functionality above with 1 `ContentProvider`. 
I don't need someone to write me tons of code (but if you do I'm ok with that too), I just want someone to help me understand how to modify the above linked examples to do these things, because I do mostly understand the examples, just not enough to translate them to my current needs.

**TL;DR;** - How do I write a single `ContentProvider` that handles multiple tables, doesn't depend on _id as the unique identifier, and handles joins along with selects that may have inner-selects/queries (such as `select count(*)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I write a single ContentProvider that handles multiple tables

Step #1: Design a REST interface for your schema, limiting yourself to a simple JSON object as the data structure (i.e., no nested arrays or objects, just a map of keys to simple values)

Step #2: Convert that design to a `ContentProvider`, replacing the `http://sooperapp.jp36.com/` with `content://com.jp36.sooperapp` and replacing the JSON with `Cursors` and `ContentValues`

So, for example, you might support `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/folder` and `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/item` and `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/subitem` as the basis of retrieving/modifying information about one or more of each of those types.

> doesn't depend on _id as the unique identifier

If you plan on using `CursorAdapter`, and assuming that by `uuid` you really do mean a UUID (which is typically a string), then you have no choice but to also have `_id`. If, however, you do not plan on using `CursorAdapter`, you have no particular need for `_id`.

> and handles joins along with selects that may have inner-selects/queries (such as select count(*))

That's all a matter of your REST interface/`ContentProvider` design. If you want to have `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/folder/count` be something you query upon that, behind the scenes, does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Folder`, knock yourself out.

(note: do not literally knock yourself out)

If you want `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/omg/omg/omg/this/is/a/long/path` to `INSERT` an `Item` and 17 `Subitems` based upon some `insert()` call to the provider, go right ahead. `ContentProvider` is merely a facade; it is up to you to define what the `Uri` means, what the `ContentValues` mean, what the `query()` parameters mean, etc.

Personally, I would recommend that you step back and ask yourself why you are bothering with a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Ok, so lots of questions. ----- 1. When I am creating the `ContentProvider`, do I have a class for each table, with each class defining `CONTENT_URI` as `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/{tablename}/*` and then have separate content_uri's in the individual table classes such as `CONTENT_FROM_PARENT_URI` which would be something like `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/{tablename}/fromparent/*` defined within those objects? ----- 2. If I did query upon `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/folder/count`how would I handle the `String[] projection` parameter that is passed in along with my prebuilt sql statement?

Comment: Basically, I'm pretty sure I could figure out some way to use `ContentProvider` to do what I am after, my problems come from trying to figure out the ***right/best practice*** way to do it so that the next person who uses this library will be able to use it similarly to other Android provided `ContentProviders`. ------- Also, I want to use a `ContentProvider` because of nice integration with CursorLoaders and possible SyncAdapter use in the future. ------- Thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: @jp36: "do I have a class for each table" -- well, you could have the `ContentProvider` delegate logic to separate classes if you want, that's up to you. You would only have one `ContentProvider`, though, as those are tied to the "authority" (`com.jp36.sooperapp` in my examples). Basically, everything to the right of the authority is up for you to interpret, with the exception of the instance ID for `Uri` values pointing to a specific record (it's the integer segment on the far right).

Comment: @jp36: "how would I handle the String[] projection parameter" -- you could ignore it, if you want. Again, `ContentProvider` is a facade. Other than the `Uri`, you define what the parameters to `query()` mean.

Comment: @firstcomment assuming separate classes were used to be similar to how Android does it, would each class defining CONTENT_URI as `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/{tablename}/*` and then having separate `content_uri`'s in the individual table classes such as `CONTENT_FROM_PARENT_URI` (which would be something like `content://com.jp36.sooperapp/{tablename}/fromparent/*`) be the way to do it?

Comment: @secondcomment wouldn't ignoring the projection parameter be counter-intuitive for any future developers using my `contentprovider` vs using other `contentproviders`?

Comment: @jp36: I cannot understand anything from your second-to-last comment, and I cannot solve all your problems with respect to your last comment. I will delete this answer if you would prefer to try to get more input from others -- just let me know.

Comment: don't delete; your answer is helpful and like 90%, I'm just trying to close that 10% gap with these questions. ------ if I had `public class Item`, which had `public static Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(content://com.jp36.sooperapp/item/*)` would it follow the android model to also define `public static Uri  CONTENT_FROM_PARENT_URI = CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath("fromparent").build()` so users could query using `CONTENT_FROM_PARENT_URI` and just append a UUID

Comment: @jp36: Ah, now I get that part. That's not a bad thing to do. You'll see that sort of thing in the more complex providers that Android supplies. In their case, they tend to go with static inner classes and the like, packaging up static data members for column names, the `CONTENT_URI`, etc. Effectively, each `CONTENT_URI` gets a Java "namespace" for all the relevant constants associated with it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm the sole android developer here with no one to bounce things like this off of. Final question (SO related) should I delete my two similar comments which weren't clear to clean this answer up for future readers?

Comment: @jp36: Nah, don't worry about it.